# Does information about rsyslog apply to syslog?

Tags: logging, logstash, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to configure syslog to send events to a remote server running Logstash. I can only find information about using rsyslog with Logstash, rather than syslog with Logstash.

Will most of the information pertaining to rsyslog be applicable to my task using syslog?

Comment: There is a Logstash input plugin for syslog here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legacy syslog has many similarities to rsyslog, but other than simple functionality not much carries over.